# How to convert hex to NSColor?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6

I have this function which transform a color in hexString :

```
public extension NSColor {
    func getHexString() -> String {
        let red = Int(round(self.redComponent * 0xFF))
        let green = Int(round(self.greenComponent * 0xFF))
        let blue = Int(round(self.blueComponent * 0xFF))
        let hexValue = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
        return hexValue
    }
}
```

Now , i have no idea  how to reverse this. 
All i have is this objective-c code , but i'm not able to convert it to swift.

```
 (NSColor*)colorWithHexColorString:(NSString*)inColorString
{
    NSColor* result = nil;
    unsigned colorCode = 0;
    unsigned char redByte, greenByte, blueByte;

    if (nil != inColorString)
    {
         NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inColorString];
         (void) [scanner scanHexInt:&colorCode]; 
    }
    redByte = (unsigned char)(colorCode >> 16);
    greenByte = (unsigned char)(colorCode >> 8);
    blueByte = (unsigned char)(colorCode);

    result = [NSColor
    colorWithCalibratedRed:(CGFloat)redByte
    green:(CGFloat)greenByte 
    blue:(CGFloat)blueByte 
    alpha:1.0];
    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exact same thing with swift, however this uses UIColor rather than NSColor,

```
func colorWithHexColorString(var colorString: String) -> UIColor?
{
    if colorString.hasPrefix("#") {
        colorString = dropFirst(colorString)
    }

    var color: UIColor? = nil

    var colorCode = UInt32()

    var redByte:CGFloat = 255;
    var greenByte:CGFloat = 255;
    var blueByte: CGFloat = 255;

    let scanner = NSScanner(string: colorString)
    if scanner.scanHexInt(&colorCode) {
        redByte = CGFloat(colorCode & 0xff0000)
        greenByte = CGFloat(colorCode & 0x00ff00)
        blueByte =  CGFloat(colorCode & 0xff)
        color = UIColor(red: redByte, green: greenByte, blue: blueByte, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    return color
}

colorWithHexColorString("#ffff00")
colorWithHexColorString("ff0000")
```

Comment: `colorString = colorString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(1, colorString.length - 1))` Yecccccch! You can do that _so_ much more tightly and legibly - and without dropping into Foundation - simply by calling `dropFirst(colorString)`.

Comment: Wow, I didnt know about that. I tried to do it the way it used to be in Objective C. I edited my answer. Thanks @matt.

Comment: I was about to say that you should use String

Comment: I did it now. @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Thanks. It seem that now i have a new problem . The returned color is not the same with the started color.

Comment: @C-Viorel "the returned color is not the same" - the above code selects the components from the 24-bit value, `& 0x...`, but omits the divide/shift to make each in the range 0..255.

Comment: Thanks;  I finally figured out how to do it. This was my first attempt working with core data and did not know how I could save a color or an image. In the end I use NSData.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I'm doing this, but with all due respect, I was disturbed by the way "insane-36" was resorting to NSScanner and NSString - it all just seemed too heavyweight - so here's my "pure" Swift version, which is not actually "pure" because I ended up calling `strtol`:

```
func hexStringToColor(var s:String) -> UIColor {
    if s.hasPrefix("#") { s = dropFirst(s) }
    var arr = [String]()
    for i in stride(from: 0, through: 4, by: 2) {
        let ix = advance(s.startIndex,i)
        let ix2 = advance(s.startIndex,i+1)
        arr.append(s[ix...ix2])
    }
    let rgb = arr.map{CGFloat(strtol($0,nil,16))/255.0}
    return UIColor(red: rgb[0], green: rgb[1], blue: rgb[2], alpha: 1)
}
```